# Oracle Apex IG 5.1 set data value

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I tried to update a single row in an interactive grid using JavaScript only. I can not use the Interactive Grid Automatic Row Processing due to clients condition.

I followed the Interactive Grid Hack Guide and wrote the following code. When I press the Update Button, the IG refreshes but nothing really happens. My IG has the Static ID of 'interactive'.

```
apex.region("interactive").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").set("edit", true);
var grid = apex.region("interactive").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid");
var records = grid.model.getSelectedRecords();
var model = grid.model; 
var record = model.getRecord("interactive");
model.setValue(record, 'mail', &MAIL.);
```

Comment: So, you are using Apex, but the client has told you not to use its built-in capabilities. That's strange, don't you think? As of your question - no idea, sorry, my JavaScript knowledge is *less than zero*.

Comment: in the line `var record = model.getRecord("interactive");` what is "interactive"? As far as I know it should be row id